# Why does my asyncio function stop after the first task?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

This is my first attempt at asynchronous programming in Python, but I am running into a problem where my results stop after the first task is finished, as opposed to returning *all* of the results after *every* task has finished executing.

In `api.py`, I have a `search_async` function that ultimately makes the request using the aiohttp.ClientSession object being passed around. Then the `search_value_async` function as a wrapper that's being called in `app.py`

```
# api.py

async def search_async(self, session, offset=0):
    endpoint = 'https://example.com'
    query_string = urlencode({ 'offset': offset })

    lookup_url = f'{endpoint}?{query_string)}'

    async with session.get(lookup_url, headers=self.get_resource_headers()) as response:
        if response.status not in range(200, 299):
            return {
                'Status': response.status
            }

        return await response.json()

async def search_value_async(self, session, offset=0):
    return await self.search_async(session, offset)
```

```
# app.py
async def get_recommendations(queries):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        data = await get_all_queries(session, queries)
        return data


async def get_all_queries(session, queries):
    tasks = []

    for query in queries:
        for offset in range(0, 1000, 50):
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(api.search_value_async(session, query, offset)))

    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results

def main():
    # queries = ...
    data = []

    results = asyncio.run(get_recommendations(queries))

    data.extend(results)
    recommendations = normalize_data(data)

    return data
```

So far, I've confirmed that the correct number of coroutines are being created, and I was able to diagnose that the number of results I get back when running asynchronously is equivalent to only the first task being ran.

I'm new to this, so my understanding could be wrong, but if all my tasks are being created, I would expect the results from `await aysncio.gather(*tasks)` to give me the results from *all* of my completed tasks, not just the first one.

Comment: Re " was able to diagnose that the number of results I get back when running asynchronously is equivalent to only the first task being ran", what is the output of `len(results)` and `len(queries)` in `main()` after calling `asyncio.run()`?

Comment: And this may just be a testing thing but why the `offset` loop in `get_all_queries()`? That seems to be running the same query many times.

Comment: And, just being pedantic, `299` is also a successful HTTP response code so your detection for this should probably be `range(200, 300)`.

Comment: @paxdiablo `len(results)` returns 60, which is equal to the number of total tasks I'm expecting. And `len(queires)` is 3. For each query, there's 20 requests built. The api has a max offset of 1000 and returns a max of 50 results, which is why I run the offset loop to generate each of these requests with it's appropriate offset value

Comment: That makes sense, Ethan, but it's not immediately obvious how `offset` is being delivered to the async task. That's *possibly* in the "here i am running code to format the lookup_url argument" bit but it's worth checking. You *are* getting the correct result count (60 = 20 queries by 3 sets) but, if it's the exact same query for each set (`offset` not being used), that may explain your issue.

Comment: Oh, it’s being passed as an argument, I forgot to include that. I’m on my phone rn but when I get home I can update the post. But that value is being passed to `search_values_async` and then `search_async`, which is ultimately used in that lookup_url argument. I think you might be right though, I’ll check that when I get home

Comment: I also ask, as @paxdiablo did, about the statement "the number of results I get back when running asynchronously is equivalent to only the first task being ran."  You later say that len(results) is 60 and len(queries) is 3, which would seem to be exactly what you would expect if all the tasks (not just the first one) are being run.  If only the first task is running, 1 task cannot produce 60 results.  What data is in those 60 results?

Comment: @Paul, my suspicion is that there are the correct number of results but, since the offset is not being used correctly, each set (a "page" of 50 items) is identical. In other words, the first page is being returned multiple times (and probably de-duped).

Comment: @paxdiabl I updated the post so that it shows how I am passing the `offset` value around.   After testing, it doesn't appear to be that the same offset value is being re-ran and returning duplicate results.

Comment: I've confirmed that the correct `lookup_url` value is being requested each time as well

Comment: Okay, so then you need to print out the full content of `data` after the extend (use `pprint` for readability). This will tell you what it contains. It's worth doing the same after the normalisation call in case that changes `data` as well. And just verify that you want to return `data` rather than `recommendations`.

Comment: @paxdiablo Found out the issue was in my data normalization. I was refactoring some older functionality and some leftover code was only normalizing the first index of data in the response object instead of the whole thing. Thanks for helping me dig around that mess, I was about to lose my mind there.